# What is analog of Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10") in ASP. NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, page-refresh

Would someone tell me if there is an analog of `Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10")` in ASP. NET MVC5, please?

I have tried `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 10)]` but it does not work.

Comment: You can use `Response.AddHeader()` in MVC5. What are you trying to accomplish? What "does not work"?

Comment: @Jasen I assume should be some method attribute tag to do it, right?

Comment: Add it directly in the controller action. Or make a custom action filter to get the attribute style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it directly in your controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10");
    return View();
}
```

Or you can make a custom action filter

```
public class RefreshAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var duration = 10;

        Int32.TryParse(this.Duration, out duration);            

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Refresh", duration.ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage

```
[Refresh(Duration = "10")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`[OutputCache]` is for, well, caching the output of an action. The `Duration` param merely tells it how long to cache that output. Neither has *anything* to do with setting HTTP headers, and certainly will not make a page refresh automatically.

`Reponse.AddHeader` is still valid in MVC5; you just need to ensure that you have not started the response yet. Unless you're doing something off-the-wall, that's not difficult. If you're returning a `ViewResult`, for example, just call this first:

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10");
return View();
```

If you're directly writing to the response, then just ensure you add the header before you start doing that.